# MvvmCross Community SQLite plugin - NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am developing a Xamarin app (currently for Android) with SQLite plugin onboard.
One of the first methods I added to work with db is following:

```
public ItemType FindItemById<ItemType> (int id) where ItemType : IDataItem, new()
{
    return connection.Table<ItemType> ().Where (item => item.id == id).FirstOrDefault ();
}
```

The following exception is thrown when I call the method:

```
InnerException was NotSupportedException: Cannot compile: Parameter
      at Community.SQLite.TableQuery`1[Prototype.Core.Services.DataStore.Product].CompileExpr (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expr, System.Collections.Generic.List`1 queryArgs) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Community.SQLite.TableQuery`1[Prototype.Core.Services.DataStore.Product].CompileExpr (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expr, System.Collections.Generic.List`1 queryArgs) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Community.SQLite.TableQuery`1[Prototype.Core.Services.DataStore.Product].CompileExpr (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expr, System.Collections.Generic.List`1 queryArgs) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Community.SQLite.TableQuery`1[Prototype.Core.Services.DataStore.Product].CompileExpr (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expr, System.Collections.Generic.List`1 queryArgs) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Community.SQLite.TableQuery`1[Prototype.Core.Services.DataStore.Product].GenerateCommand (System.String selectionList) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Community.SQLite.TableQuery`1[Prototype.Core.Services.DataStore.Product].GetEnumerator () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Prototype.Core.Services.DataStore.Product].AddEnumerable (IEnumerable`1 enumerable) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Prototype.Core.Services.DataStore.Product]..ctor (IEnumerable`1 collection) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[Product] (IEnumerable`1 source) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Community.SQLite.TableQuery`1[Prototype.Core.Services.DataStore.Product].FirstOrDefault () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Prototype.Core.Services.DataStore.Repository.FindItemById[Product] (Int32 id) [0x0000e] in e:\Projects\Mobile\AppMaster\crossplatform\Prototype\Prototype.Core\Services\DataStore\Repository.cs:55 
  at Prototype.Core.ViewModels.SingleProductViewModel.Init (Prototype.Core.ViewModels.Navigation navigation) [0x00022] in e:\Projects\Mobile\AppMaster\crossplatform\Prototype\Prototype.Core\ViewModels\SingleProductViewModel.cs:28
```

Could someone explain what am I doing wrong?

Added:

This has something to do with the "genericity" of this method.  When I wrote it like this (usual non-generic method):

```
public Product FindProductById (int id)
{
    return connection.Table<Product> ().Where (product => product.id == id).Select (product => product).FirstOrDefault ();
}
```

it started working... Could it be a bug in SQLite plugin?

Comment: Update: for this particular case one can use connection.Find which can easily be used in template methods.

Comment: Hey I'm having the same issue when using it with Generic Types. Strangely it works fine when I build on a Mac(Xamarin) but not when I build the same project on Windows. connection.Find returns only one record. I want to load a list. Any thoughts? I have a feeling this is a bug too..